# Does the Jedi mind trick have any negative effects on the Jedi performing it?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

The mind trick is obviously a very useful power for Force users, provided that the recipient is susceptible to it (i.e. "weak-minded"), which makes me curious as to why they don't try to use it more often.  Are there certain drawbacks to attempting to use the Jedi mind trick (regardless of whether or not the trick is successful)?  For example, would it have something like a draining effect on the power of the Jedi using it and they, therefore, need to avoid trying to use it too much?  Or do they refrain from attempting it for entirely different reasons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is according to the Wookieepedia article on [Jedi Mind Tricks](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_trick):

"When instructing Jedi students, Yarael Poof stressed that a user must be mindful when utilizing this ability, that their target was nevertheless a living being with lives of their own, and that extra precaution must be exercised as their command could potentially ruin their target's life."

So there seems to be no negative effects on the user, just a strong moral obligation on how they use the power. This of course only applies to Jedi. Sith would have no objections on over using or abusing the power to get the results they wanted

Comment: Ruin lives? Yep. Tell that to the two Stormtroopers from Mos Eisley. They were most likely horrendously executed.

Comment: Undoubtedly they were, but keep in mind that the jedi order no longer existed and Ben had no love for The Empire or it's soldiers. He also knew that if R2 was taken it would have crippled or put an end to the rebellion.

Comment: it was just an example to back you up :P not an "anti-Obi-Wan" post. I am strickly pro-Obi-Wan

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your comment. It's extremely late here and my brain is running on empty.

Comment: Would you say you were feeling... weak-minded?

Comment: Exactly. I must admit i was feeling that way.